# Most efficient way to check byte array values are within a range/below threshold?

Tags: arrays, validation, solidity

I have a `uint256` that I'm using as a byte array consisting of 10 numbers, 3 bytes each (which takes up 30 bytes, the first 2 bytes of the 32 bytes are ignored):

```
0x0000aaaaaabbbbbbccccccddddddeeeeeeffffff111111222222333333444444
  xxxx^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^
```

I need to validate that these numbers are within a certain range. They are `uint24` so they are always positive, and the lowest index is 0 so I only really need to check if they are below a certain upper threshold.

At present I am reading the relevant bytes into `uint24` objects and checking that the number is below the threshold:

```
uint256 constant NUM_OF_GROUPS = 129600; // all numbers have to be between 0 and 129599

....... 

function decodeAndCheckGroupIndexes(uint256 x)
        public
        pure
        returns (
            uint24 a,
            uint24 b,
            uint24 c,
            uint24 d,
            uint24 e,
            uint24 f,
            uint24 g,
            uint24 h,
            uint24 i,
            uint24 j
        )
    {
        assembly {
            j := x
            mstore(0x1B, x)
            a := mload(0)
            mstore(0x18, x)
            b := mload(0)
            mstore(0x15, x)
            c := mload(0)
            mstore(0x12, x)
            d := mload(0)
            mstore(0x0F, x)
            e := mload(0)
            mstore(0x0C, x)
            f := mload(0)
            mstore(0x09, x)
            g := mload(0)
            mstore(0x06, x)
            h := mload(0)
            mstore(0x03, x)
            i := mload(0)
        }
        require(
            a < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                b < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                c < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                d < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                e < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                f < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                g < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                h < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                i < NUM_OF_GROUPS &&
                j < NUM_OF_GROUPS,
            "group is out of range"
        ); 
    }
```

however I was wondering if there was a better way to check it involving less computation? This check happens in a loop with an array of `uint256` so I'm attempting to achieve maximum efficiency to reduce gas cost.

Comment: Any specificity on the upper limit? And is it the same upper limit for every value?

Comment: Yes every value has the same upper limit

Comment: variable, or fixed upper limit? what is the upper limit if fixed?

Comment: Fixed upper limit, defined as a constant as part of the contract

Comment: So what I was thinking is if the upper limit were fixed enough, and a power of 2, you could create a bitmask like 0xF00F00F00 and xor against that - if anything hits you've exceeded the limit. If values are much more dynamic, that won't work. Your other option might be to just make them all 32-bit, use a little more memory, it's probably just as fast, maybe faster, given dealing with bit alignment.

Comment: so in this case the NUM_OF_GROUPS is 129600 (which is a power of 2) so all values have to be between 0 and 129599. Added it to the code above for clarity.

Comment: That's a multiple of 2, not power of 2. You could still do something similar. In that case mask the top 3 (unused, too large) bits.  So over=0xE00000E000000.... repeated. Do your int256 xor over, and if that is > 0, then some value is definitely over. Assuming none, then do maybe=0x100000100000... xor your int256, and if that's > 0, then some value _could_ be over, and you need to check every one. If values are rarely "large" it might help.

Comment: Or just xor with F00000F00000... and if that tests > 0, then do the long version compare of each value. That would also be easy to figure out what that masks needs to be for any dynamic value, just mask up to and including the highest bit, and repeat.

Comment: Just realised I had the ignored bytes placement wrong, its the first 2 bytes that are ignored (addressed above) but I assume your suggestions would still hold, just the masks will need shifting by 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 24-bit unsigned binary representation of `129,600` is `000000011111101001000000`, which has all 0s in its 7 leftmost bits.

#### Checking a 24-bit Number

If a 24-bit unsigned number has all 0s in its 8 leftmost bits, then it is less than or equal to `65,535`, and consequently less than `129,600`.

If a 24-bit unsigned number has a 1 in its 7 leftmost bits, then it is greater than or equal to `131,072`, and consequently greater than `129,600`.

This can be used to check if a 24-bit unsigned number definitely passes or definitely fails to be less than `129,600`.

If a bitwise `and` between the number and `0xFF0000` is zero, then the number passes the check (less than `129,600`).

Otherwise, if a bitwise `and` between the number and `0xFE0000` is non-zero, then the number fails the check (greater than `129,600`).

Otherwise, the number can be compared directly with `129,600`.

#### Extending the Check to Ten 24-bit Numbers

For the 256-bit `uint256` value that encodes 10 24-bit numbers—as described in the question—each of the first two checks (definitely pass or definitely fail) can be conducted for all 10 numbers with a 256-bit mask and corresponding bitwise `and`.

If a bitwise `and` between the `uint256` value and the following mask is zero, then the 10 numbers pass the check, since none of the numbers have 1s in their 8 leftmost bits (all numbers are less than or equal to `65,535`, and consequntly less than `129,600`).

```
0x0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000
  xxxx^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^
```

Otherwise, if a bitwise `and` between the `uint256` value and the following mask is non-zero, then the numbers fail the check, since at least one number has a 1 in its 7 leftmost bits (at least one number is greater than or equal to `131,072`, and consequently greater than `129,600`).

```
0x0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000
  xxxx^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^
```

Otherwise, the 10 numbers can be compared directly with `129,600` using the approach proposed in the question.

#### Summary

This approach allows a way to quickly check if all 10 numbers definitely pass or at least one number definitely fails. In the case where there is no definite pass or definite fail, then a more computationally demanding procedure can be used to check each of the 10 numbers individually (with short-circuiting on failure).

#### Pseudocode

(`&` is used to represent bitwise `and`)

```c
uint256 valid_mask = 0x0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000;
uint256 invalid_mask = 0x0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000FE0000;

// returns true if all ten numbers encoded in `input` are
// less than 129,600
bool less_than_129600(uint256 input) {
    // check if all ten numbers are definitely valid
    if (valid_mask & input == 0)
        return true;
    
    // check if at least one number is definitely invalid
    if (invalid_mask & input != 0)
        return false;

    // check each number and return false if an invalid number
    // is encountered
    ...

    // if we haven't returned after the last check, all numbers
    // are valid
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, shame that there's no direct way to check but this is definitely going to help. The bounty expired though I'm not sure how i can reward you some points?